For any $p, q \in [1,\infty]$ and $s \in (0,\infty)$, can we find some $f \in L^q - W^{s,p}$?
Sobolev inequalities show us when we can embed a Sobolev space into another.
However, I wonder if these inclusions are always proper.
More specifically, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set and $p,q \in [1,\infty]$ while $s \in (0,\infty)$. My question is:

For any such triplet $(s,p,q)$, can we find some $f \in L^q(\Omega)$ such that $f \notin W^{s,p}(\Omega)$?

For non-integer $s$, I am aware that there are two definitions of the Sobolev space: Bessel potential vs Sobolev–Slobodeckij and I am asking the above above question for both cases.
In fact, I am thinking of the Heaviside step function as a plausible example working for all $(s,p,q)$, as in this ME post.
Still, I cannot fully justify my guess. Could anyone please help me?

Since all your spaces are Banach, an inclusion like $L^q(\Omega)\subset W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ implies (by the closed graph theorem) a continuous embedding. Such an embedding is impossible due to compactness : $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ embedds compactly in $L^1(\Omega)$ whereas $L^q(\Omega)$ does not.

Does your argument work for any $s \in (0,\infty)$ and $p,q \in [1,\infty]$?

Well, I believe so !

I just want to check if $W^{s,p}$ is compactly embedded into $L^1$ for all $s, p$, because I cannot find a relevant theorem in the link in my post.

Check Theorem 7.1 in the arXiv version of Di Nezza, Palatucci and Valdinoci Hitchiker's guide. Of course I assumed that your domain was regular enough to invoke embeddings theorems.

A particular domain I have in mind is in fact the $n$-torus $\mathbb{T}^n : = (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n$. So, I think it should be regular enough.
